# Why use Implicit and Explicit Transaction Modes in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Reading MS documentation on different transaction modes in SQL Server.
Autocommit mode does everything the Implicit and Explicit Transaction mode does with less code, so why should I use Implicit and Explicit Transaction modes in my code ?

Comment: "Autocommit mode does everything the Implicit and Explicit Transaction mode does" - really? Because one of the most important things that those do is to leave the transaction neither committed nor rolled back after a single statement has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocommit transaction is only for single query. If you need transaction involving multiple queries, you must use Implicit and Explicit Transaction mode.

Answer (score 0):

As you know sqlserver automatically done the job of transaction commit. But some time we need to commit /rollback on particular condition/logic/business rule(s).

For example, we have one master table and 3 child/details table or say 1 or more child tables.
Suppose, we must save master table entry along with all details table with reference of master table's pk-id. In any case anything an issue then revert whole thing.

So in this scenerio we need to use explicit transaction to commit or rollback as a unit of work. We can use try..catch block for error handling and rollback the transaction.

If we not used this transaction, then after each insert statement sqlserver auto-commit the inserted row and not rollback ever.